# Get a single value of JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have this json object created using the code below:

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e, Formatting.Indented);
                    var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

                    Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

I get this result:

[image]

I need to get the value of RSSI only. Can you please show me? Thank you.

Comment: Is the code that created this your code? Then why mess with the JSON at all? Don't you have the object `e` which you serialized?

Comment: Do you want to deserialize only one property instead of deserializing whole json string?? or do you want to print value of RSSI? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @pstrjds: I know that. I just want to know how to do it cause I am planning to change it.